# Hyphenation of a language doesn't work in TexLive

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia

I am trying to implement hyphenation patterns for Armenian from `hyph-utf8`, but `polyglossia` doesn't recognise it with the message

```
Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `armenian'

(polyglossia)                I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on i
nput line 12.
```

I have installed `hyph-utf8` and its Armenian part `hyph-hy` by `tlmgr`, run `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` and checked the `language.dat` file, but it doesn't help.

What is wrong and what should I do?

P.S. Babel does not support Armenian, the package `armtex` does not have hyphenation patterns at all, and there is nothing about Armenian hyphenation in `polyglossia` either.

UPD: After I installed `hyphen-armenian` via `texlive-lang-other` and not manually with `tlmgr`, the hyphenation patterns loaded. The problem was with the installation and not with polyglossia.

Comment: I’d just like to point out `babel` *does* support Armenian. In my tests, the patterns are loaded and words are hyphenated (both xetex and luatex).

Comment: @JavierBezos `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[armenian,showlanguages]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
Բարեւ աշխարհ
\end{document}` shows that armenian patterns are loaded `9^^Iarmenian^^Iloadhyph-hy.tex^^I`  but gives a warning that no armenian.ldf available?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle See https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/which-method-for-which-language.html#loading-the-language .

Comment: @JavierBezos ooh documentation, Ulrike will be pleased:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And also: https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/main/samples/luahb-udhr.pdf . Just use the `ini` interface, with `provide`.

Comment: @JavierBezos I posted something, hope that's not completely wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[armenian,provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont[armenian]{rm}{FreeSerif}
\begin{document}
Բարեւ աշխարհ
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above with some help from Javier, hope I got that right.

Comment: Redundant: `\usepackage{fontspec}` (loaded by `babel`) and `[armenian]` (just use the font for all languages). Anyway, this doesn’t solve the issue if the OP *does* want to use `polyglossia`. I just wanted to point out a wrong assumption wrt `babel`.

Comment: @JavierBezos thanks, yes realised that fontspec was redundant by the time I'd finished. maybe I'll delete it. I'll leave the armenian option on the font setting as possibly in real cases you need different fonts for the different scripts. True the OP asked about polyglossia but (as you know:-) the patterns are loaded or not at format creation time not as a result of the package loading.

Answer (score 1):

This works with no problem on my TeX Live 2021:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{armenian}
\newfontfamily{\armenianfont}{Mshtakan}

\begin{document}

Ա

\the\language

\the\csname l@armenian\endcsname

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

so the language is known by `language.dat` and is selected properly.

Comment: But do the hyphenation patterns load?

Comment: @Quaternion If I try to fully hyphenate a random text from the Armenian Wikipedia, I get hyphens.

Comment: @Quaternion Run the following document and a look at the log file for the list of loaded patterns: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[showlanguages]{babel} \stop`